# Missing type map configuration exception is showing in my code

Tags: .net-core, automapper, repository-pattern

I have the following code in the controller and showing exception.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult GetCategoryGoalsById(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var categories = _unitOfWork.Category.GetCategoryByGoalId(id);
            if (categories == null)
            {
                _loggerManager.LogError($"Category with id: {id}, hasn't been found in db.");
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                _loggerManager.LogInfo($"Returned category with id: {id}");
                var categoryResult = _mapper.Map<CategoryDetailVm>(categories);
                return Ok(categoryResult);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _loggerManager.LogError($"Something went wrong inside categoryResult action: {ex.Message}");
            return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
        }
    }
```

Where is the entity class is like this:

```
public class Category 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Goals))]
    public int GoalId { get; set; } 
    public Goals Goals { get; set; }

}
```

and vm class  for the module class written as:

```
public class CategoryDetailVm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    
}
```

The code is written in repository pattern with UnitofWork and the repository part is written as:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategoryByGoalId(int goalId)
    {
        return FindByCondition(g => g.Goals.Id.Equals(goalId)).ToList();
    }
```

following exception is showing here, how can I resolve the following problem:

> - ```
>   ex  {"Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nObject ->
>   ```
>
> CategoryDetailVm\r\nSystem.Object ->
> EthosAPI.ViewModelEntities.CategoryDetailVm"} System.Exception
> {AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're missing an automapper mapping, did you add it?
https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html#how-do-i-use-automapper

eg. `var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<CategoryDetailVm, Categorie>());`

Also you're mapping an object to an entire list, so you should also have a mapping for lists, see:
https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html

So `var categoryResult = _mapper.Map<CategoryDetailVm>(categories);` should be more like                 `var categoryResult = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CategoryDetailVm>>(categories);` or something.

Comment: Thanks, Code is working now: using : var categoryResult = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CategoryDetailVm>>(categories);